# What is the best practice for future proofing my editor enumerations?

Tags: editors

I would like to know the best practices for handling the following situation:

---

Suppose the project you are working on is split in to two sub-projects; the game engine library, and the editor GUI.

You have the method `bool Method( const MethodParams &params )` that will be called during game-level initialization; it is a method that belongs to the game engine library. The parameters of this method, passed as a reference to the structure `MethodParams`, can be decided via the editor in the level design phase. The `MethodParams` structure is as follows:

```
enum Enum1
{
    E1_VAL1,
    E1_VAL2,
};

enum Enum2
{
    E2_VAL1,
    E2_VAL2,
    E2_VAL3,
};

struct MethodParams
{
    float   value;
    Enum1   e1;
    Enum2   e2;
    // some other members
}
```

The editor should present a dialog that will allow the user to set the values in the `MethodParams` structure. The editor needs to present a text box for `value`, and let the user set the fields `e1` and `e2` using a combo box, for example. Every enum option should be mapped to a string, so the user can make an informed selection (normally, the names used in the enum would be more meaningful). One could even want to map every enum to a more informative string (so, for example, `E1_VAL1` could map to "Image union algorithm", and `E1_VAL2` could map to "Image intersection algorithm").

---

The editor will include all the relevant game engine library files (.h, etc.), but this mapping is not automatic, and I am confused by how to handle it in a way that where code change will be minimal, if I add further enum options in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute easiest way to map this is to use an `std::map`. That's what it's for.

```
std::map<Enum1, std::string> map_enum1;

map_enum1.insert<std::pair<Enum1, std::string>>(E1_VAL1, "Image union algorithm");
map_enum1.insert<std::pair<Enum1, std::string>>(E1_VAL2, "Image intersection algorithm");
```

This has several advantages:

- Uses tried-and-tested tools.
- No hacky precompiler trickery to map the values at compile-time.
- Able to change values at run-time.
- Easy to translate to other languages.

Adding new enums will continue to be difficult though, because it requires a recompile. However, if you step down from `enum`s to simple `int`'s, you can always add new values without requiring recompilation.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to map enumerations to strings, you can use the following question on SO:
[How to easily map c++ enums to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207976/how-to-easily-map-c-enums-to-strings).